# xinput mouse setting not persistent during session

Tags: x11, mouse, xinput

I use linux Manjaro Gnome X11.
I like to have a special setting of mouse buttons, which I obtain with `xinput`.

In order to make this setting persistent across sessions, I write the `xinput` in `~/.xprofile` and indeed it works at the beginning of every session.

However it stops working after some time within a given session (no logout).

A Gnome startup item (`~/.config/autostart/*.desktop`) can be used instead `~/.xprofile`.

```
alba@mac2011-manjaro% journalctl -b _UID=1000 -t /usr/lib/gdm-x-session|grep Logitech
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) event5  - Logitech M350: device removed
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech M350
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech M350
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech M350 (/dev/input/mouse0)
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech M350 (/dev/input/event5)
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech M350'
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: always reports core events
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) event5  - Logitech M350: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) event5  - Logitech M350: device is a pointer
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) event5  - Logitech M350: device is a keyboard
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) event5  - Logitech M350: device removed
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) libinput: Logitech M350: needs a virtual subdevice
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech M350" (type: MOUSE, id 14)
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: (accel) selected scheme none/0
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) event5  - Logitech M350: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) event5  - Logitech M350: device is a pointer
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) event5  - Logitech M350: device is a keyboard
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech M350'
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (**) Logitech M350: always reports core events
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) libinput: Logitech M350: is a virtual subdevice
Mar 12 23:04:55 mac2011-manjaro /usr/lib/gdm-x-session[15562]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech M350" (type: KEYBOARD, id 15)
```

What breaks my setting?  How to make it completely persistent during session?

Comment: Instead of using xinput, did you try defining your special mouse settings as part of some xorg.conf file ? (because these settings are supposed to persist after suspend / hibernation)

Comment: I mean having something looking like Section "InputClass" / Identifier  "someindentifyingstring" / Option  "ButtonMapping" "you personal list of numbers" / EndSection

Comment: The mouse is wireless with USB dongle and a power button.  Disconnecting the dongle breaks the setting but switching off the mouse (or removing its power supply) does not break the setting.

Comment: A problem exists in principle. I need a setting that triggers on mouse connection not X11 startup. Even if the mouse works well, I may need to disconnect it to free the USB port.

Comment: xorg.conf can't work because it applies to all user.  My mouse setting is personal, I have no reason to impose it to all users.

Answer (score 0):

Low level solution: I have set up a background job with infinite loop.

```
alba@mac2011-manjaro% cat ~/.xprofile
# This file is read at X11 start.
# In Fedora use ~/.config/autostart/*.desktop instead.
# # avoid spurious paste while scrolling
# # find the device number
# # repeat forever
while sleep 1
do xinput list|grep pointer|tail -1|grep -o 'id=[0-9]*'|grep -o '[0-9]*'|xargs -I{} xinput set-button-map {} 1 3 2
done&
```

This can't be done with `crontab` because cron job can't connect to X server (and one minute is too short anyway).

Comment: I also found out the cause of disturbance: a defective cable plugged on the next USB socket.